# Parse JSON Array that contains string and int in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift

I have a simple array

```
Array[4][
 "A",
  1,
 "A1",
  13
]
```

But how can i parse an JSON array when it contains both int and string? I have no problem converting all the values inside to string if they aren't already, but i can't find any function to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Complicated way with `Codable`

   - Decode the array with `unkeyedContainer`
   - Use a `while` loop with condition `!isAtEnd` and decode `Int` in a `do - catch` block. If it fails decode `String`
2. Easy way with traditional `JSONSerialization`

   - Deserialize the object to `[CustomStringConvertible]` and map the array to `[String]` with `"\($0)"`

**Edit:**

This is an example how to decode the array with `Decodable` if the items are pairs and the type order is the same:

```
let jsonArray = """
["A", 1, "A1", 13]
"""

struct Item : Decodable {
    var array = [String]()

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var arrayContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        while !arrayContainer.isAtEnd {
            let string = try arrayContainer.decode(String.self)
            let int = try arrayContainer.decode(Int.self)
            array.append(String(int))
            array.append(string)
        }
    }
}

let data = Data(jsonArray.utf8)
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Item.self, from: data)
    print(result.array)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Oh well i wantd to keep Codable for my entire app, but this JSON is very complex (this array is just one part of the whole piece). I think i'll stick with JSONSerialization for this one.

Thanks, vadian!

Comment: If the items are pairs and the order `String`, `Int`, `String`, `Int` is guaranteed then `Codable` is less complicated and might be more efficient. In each iteration of the `while` loop decode the pairs

Comment: Yeah the order is always the same. Could you post a simple example, please? Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks a lot Vadian. You helped me a lot.

Comment: @vadian, actually the ordering can be ditched here by using `associated enum` type. No more complication for the `Codable` and much cleaner `init(from:)`. Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting `Array` of elements as `String` or `Int` which resembles with **Array of `enum`** type. So you can parse the underlying `Type` with the help of an `enum`.

Have the underlying type structured as:

```
enum StringOrIntType: Codable {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            self = try .string(container.decode(String.self))
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            do {
                self = try .int(container.decode(Int.self))
            } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
                throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(StringOrIntType.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Encoded payload not of an expected type"))
            }
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .int(let int):
            try container.encode(int)
        case .string(let string):
            try container.encode(string)
        }
    }
}
```

**Decoding process:**

```
let jsonData = """
["A", 1, "A1", 13, 15, 2, "B"]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let decodedArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([StringOrIntType].self, from:jsonData)
    // Here, you have your Array
    print(decodedArray) // [.string("A"), .int(1), .string("A1"), .int(13), .int(15), .int(2), .string("B")]

    // If you want to get elements from this Array, you might do something like below
    decodedArray.forEach({ (value) in
        if case .string(let integer) = value {
            print(integer) // "A", "A1", "B"
        }
        if case .int(let int) = value {
            print(int) // 1, 13, 15, 2
        }
    })
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> From the comment on accepted answer: **You don't need to worry about the ordering of the items anymore.**

Comment: Wow thats a nice solution! Thanks Nayem. Thats so easy that im going to change to use yours instead.

Comment: Thanks Nayem! Amazing solution. This has been useful to me almost 6 years since you authored it.

Answer (score 2):

Pasting the JSON sample `[1, "1"]` into [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/?gist=6304840ab6a8b11c7fd4c1f542263e30&l=swift) gives the following `Codable` implementation:

```
typealias IntOrStrings = [IntOrString]

enum IntOrString: Codable {
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .integer(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(IntOrString.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for IntOrString"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .integer(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is the full source](https://app.quicktype.io/?gist=6304840ab6a8b11c7fd4c1f542263e30&l=swift) that allows you to do the following:

```
let items = try IntStrings("[1, \"1\"]")
// Now you have:
// items == [.integer(1), .string("1")]
// so you can map or iterate over this
```

This is the most typesafe way to represent an int-or-string array from JSON.

Comment: On a side note, be more ___explicit___ for the error handling. You can omit the conditional binding in the `init(from:)`. See my answer.